# Why would inline assembly crash in release only?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, assembly, inline-assembly

I have a trivial function with some inline assembly. It looks like this:

```
void hwGetCpuid( u32* p, u32 ax )
{
   // printf( "hey" );
   __asm __volatile
   (   "movl %%ebx, %%esi\n\t"
       "cpuid\n\t"
       "xchgl %%ebx, %%esi"
       : "=a" (p[0]), "=S" (p[1]),
         "=c" (p[2]), "=d" (p[3])
       : "0" (ax)
   );
}
```

I'm building it with gcc. It runs correctly in debug builds. In release builds it seg faults. If I uncomment the printf it will run correctly in release as well.

I have a guess as to what could be happening - this scrap of asm is damaging in the stack somehow. In debug there is extra space on the stack, and in release, if I first call another function it also pads out the stack.

But I can't see what it is about this code that is wrong that would mess up the stack in release. Or am I off base and it is something else completely?

Update: Answer is that "ebx" was being clobbered, and not marked in the clobber-list. Correct code, second to last line:

```
: "b" "0" (ax)
```

There might be other errors here - but it does appear to run correctly in debug and release withtout the bogus printf function call.

Comment: Have you looked at the rest of the ASM code in the function in debug and release?

Comment: If this is 32-bit code then %ebx, %esi and %edi need to be preserved.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of that other question. This is the opposite. When the printf is present the function runs.

Comment: Ok. Ebx was not marked as clobbered, but it was being clobbered.

Comment: Hans: esi already is marked as clobbered because of the "=S". Why is edi being clobbered?

Comment: @RafaelBaptista As you seem to have found the solution, write an answer yourself and accept it.

Comment: running in debug and running in release mode are obviously two different things...perhaps spend more time in release than debug...what if you make it a real asm function and not inline, what happens then?  (cut the problem in half is it an inline asm syntax problem or is it a code problem)

Comment: `%ebx` isn't an input-only here. It is clobbered, and may be a problem with 32-bit ELF - as the PIC register is not general purpose.